# Comparing injective dimensions in a short exact sequence

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, injective-module

If $0→A→B→C→0$ is an exact sequence in the category of $R$-modules ($R$ commutative having unity) with injective dimensions of $A$ and $C$ both $≤n$, is that of $B$ also $≤n$? It seems to me that $Ext^{n+1}  (N,-)$ may work.

Comment: You can also prove it by "dual horseshoe lemma" - use the direct sum of injective resolutions of $A,C$ to produce one for $B$. Note that the sum of injective resolutions consists of injective modules, since finite direct sums and products coincide and injectives are closed under products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The short exact sequence $0\rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ yields a long exact sequence $... \rightarrow Ext^n(N,A) \rightarrow Ext^n(N,B)  \rightarrow Ext^n(N,C) \rightarrow Ext^{n+1}(N,A) \rightarrow Ext^{n+1}(N,B) \rightarrow Ext^{n+1}(N,C) \rightarrow ...$

Since $Ext^{m}(N,A)$ and $Ext^{m}(N,C)$ are $0$ for all $N$ and $m>n$, so is $Ext^{m}(N,B)$.